# Which other event handler than click could i use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, event-handling, click

I have a jQuery question, and I really think it is a silly one : i'm a beginner in JS and jQuery...

I'm using

```
$("#myLink").click(function(){
    $(".myClassToShow").show();
    $(".myClassToHide").hide();
});
```

to hide elements with class myClassToHide as a class attribute and show elements with class myClassToShow as a class attribute. I think this is really easy to understand :)

I didn't think it would hide every elements with the good class, but, well, it works.

My worry here is that my elements show and hide only *for few seconds* : the time my mouse click on the link.

**I would like to make myClassToShow elements remaining on the screen, when i already clicked my link, and myClassToHide elements really hide.**

For example, on the [johann Hammarstrom's website](http://johanhammarstrom.se/), when you click on "Print", all his works which are not print gone hide, and only the printing one remain.

That's kinda what i want. I searched using Firebug, but couldn't find which kind of event he used. I know a onchange is not the correct answer, so what?

Could you help me please?

(by the way, Thanks by advance for your time)

Comment: johann Hammarstrom's website is simple hide all hidable elements and show only elements with given class

Comment: I think he's used a simple `$('a').click()` handler (or at least I can't see any reason to use another method and over-complicate things).

Comment: @eicto : Yes, that is what i want to achieve. ^^
@DavidThomas : As I said, i would like to hide only few elements with a certain class, and show the others. And plus, i have other links `$('a')` in my page. So i can't simply use the `$('a').click()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're missing `e.preventDefault();`, if I understood you correctly.

```
$("#myLink").click(function(e) { // Add the event parameter.
    $(".myClassToShow").show(); // .show('fast'); for animation effect.
    $(".myClassToHide").hide(); // .hide('fast'); for animation effect.

    // Prevent the default action of the event to be triggered.
    e.preventDefault(); 

    // Or use
    return false;
});
```

The part you were looking for is in this file: http://johanhammarstrom.se/wp-content/themes/garnish/js/jquery.custom.js?ver=1.0
Search for `portfolioTerms.click`.

Comment: Well, thanks you @Mario, I think this is what i needed! :)
I forgot to add the event parameter, and well, I did not know about the "prenventDefault" function. I've to get some knowledges :)
Well, for the moment (and for eternity, i hope), this fixed the problem. Double thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you were using the example from the site you linked to you could try something like this.

```
<a class="print-link">Print</a>
<a class="show-all">show me everything</a>

<img src="something.png" class="print-img samples"/>
<img src="something.png" class="print-img samples"/>
<img src="something.png" class="print-img samples"/>
<img src="something.png" class="print-img samples"/>
<img src="something.png" class="print-img samples"/>

$('.print-link').on('click', function(){
    $('.print-img').addClass('hidden');
});

$('.show-all').on('click', function(){ 
    $('.samples').removeClass('hidden');
})

.hidden { opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; -webkit-transition: 1s all; } 
//opacity 0 will keep the space in the dom otherwise use display: none; the transition will make it fade if CSS3 is supported too :)
```

So here you are just adding or removing a class based on click events. Hope that helps.

Comment: You should be cancelling the default click action.

Comment: Hello, thanks for this other way to do this, but i really prefer to write it with the simple click action :)
But i'll keep this in head, if i want to try something else!
By touching css, i tried with $('.myClassToHide').css('display','none').. and well, that works too.

Answer (score 0):

I made this sample, it should mimic the site behaviour you pointed:

HTML

```
<div class="show_controller" data-show="hidable" >All</div>
<div class="show_controller" data-show="class1" >class1</div>
<div class="show_controller" data-show="class2" >class2</div>
<div class="show_controller" data-show="class3" >class3</div>

<div class="hidable class1">class1</div>
<div class="hidable class2">class2</div>
<div class="hidable class3">class3</div>
<div class="hidable class1 class2">class1 and class2</div>
<div class="hidable class2 class3">class2 and class3</div>
```

CSS:

```
.show_controller {
 display: inline;
 color: red;
 cursor: pointer;    
}​
```

JS

```
$('.show_controller').click(function() {
    var t = $(this);
    var for_show = '.' + t.data('show');
    $('.hidable:visible').not(for_show).hide(500);
    $(for_show).show(500);

});​
```

[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/YEeQC/)

Comment: You hide the problem from the op's original code by not making the clickable regions links.

Comment: pardon ? he never mean that he have `<a>` tags here

Comment: @epascarello I updated my answer with css, which have cursor pointer - just for your happiness

Comment: @epascarello where is keyboard accessible requerenment ? Also i see no problem to convert `div` to `a` and return `false` in handler

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/YEeQC/7/embedded/result/ that is not much different from my answer,